# Scroll the reviewing pane to the current change in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, cursor, review

I have a document with tracked changes in Word. I use the “Reviewing Pane” button to make the reviewing pane appear. When I click in the reviewing pane, the cursor in the main pane moves to the change that I clicked on.

How can I do the opposite? That is, I move around in the main pane, and I want to scroll the reviewing pane to show the next change after the current location in the main pane. I'd settle for having to place the cursor in a change in the main pane, and having a way to say “**scroll the reviewing pane to this change**”. I expected a context menu entry for that, but no dice. Toggling the reviewing pane off and back on scrolls it back up to the top, so that doesn't help.

Example: in the main pane, I go to the start of the section where I want to review changes now. There are many changes in preceding sections, so finding where the changes for my section start is cumbersome.

I'm running Word 2010, version 14.0.6129.5000.